# Trying to Assert text in Selenium But getting Error

Tags: regex, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello I am Trying to Validate Text From a Website.
I have added the image Below as well. The text has a BR tag on it as u can see. I am trying to Assert the content but i get error even though both texts are same. Here is my code snippet

```
String gr1text =landingpage.getGr1().getText();
System.out.println("Pre Trim "+gr1text);
gr1text.trim().replace("\r","").replace("\n","");
System.out.println("Post Trim "+gr1text);
Assert.assertTrue(landingpage.getEb1().isDisplayed());
String gr1expected1="Geometric Reasoning";
String gr1expected2="Part I";
String expected1= gr1expected1+System.lineSeparator()+gr1expected2;
expected1.trim().replace("\r","").replace("\n","");
System.out.println("Line seperator is "+expected1);

Assert.assertEquals(gr1text,expected1);
And Here is the Console Output i Get


Pre Trim Geometric Reasoning
Part I

Post Trim Geometric Reasoning
Part I

Line seperator is Geometric Reasoning 
Part I

java.lang.AssertionError: 
expected [Geometric Reasoning 
Part I] but found [Geometric Reasoning
Part I]
```

[You can see the text With BR Tag here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7nXP.png)

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with your code as these lines are void
`gr1text.trim().replace("\r","").replace("\n","");`

it should be

```
gr1text = gr1text.trim().replace("\r","").replace("\n","");
```

expected1 = expected1.trim().replace("\r","").replace("\n","");